# What type of lever is this cable for?

Tags: brakes, vintage, cable, schwinn

I recently bought a rear brake cable for my 60s era Schwinn:

[image]

I was expecting it to have a lever interface that looks like:

[image]

But they are clearly different:

[image]

I was browsing eBay for another cable and came across this:

[image]

Looking closer, the lever interface looks like it matches what I need:

[image]

Both packages say "Weinmann Tourist levers only, yet they are clearly different.

My question is, what type of brake cable was in the package I purchased? It doesn't look like it's meant for Tourist levers. When I return the cable I purchased to the seller on eBay, I'd like to let him know what type of cable he sent me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted a barrel end brake cable for straight brake levers.
What was sent to you is a curved or racing lever brake cable with a pear cable end (we called them mushroom).

> Cable end terminals (anchors): The steel cables have welded end pieces (see image) that are shaped to fit into slots in shifters or brake levers and because cables are not interchangeable as to their purpose, there are three main types of inner-cable sold. A brake cable has either a barrel-shaped end, for bikes without drop-handlebars, or a pear-shaped end for the racing types with drop-handlebars. Cables for shifters have a button-shaped end. The free end of a cable is usually welded so that the wires cannot fray while the cable is being threaded through its housings. **Some cables for brakes have a barrel at one end and a pear-termination at the other** so that the user can discard the one that is not needed. These latter types are referred to as universal though the term is also used to describe some products that contain a complete brake or shifting kit that is long enough to fit most bikes.
> [image]
> [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bicycles/Maintenance_and_Repair/Cables_and_Housings)

Comment: Just to clarify, brake and shifter cables are not interchangeable.  The line in the quote about shifter fables could possibly be a distraction.